# C# MVC app on Azure: Site works fine when freshly deployed but fails after being left idle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have spent a good bit of time researching this but have not found anybody else reporting the issue that I am having.

I deploy my site and everything is good.  I share the link with my QA and UI peeps and everything works for them.  But if the site goes for a period of time, such as overnight, without being accessed then the web application is unable to start and reports "Method 'get_CurrentUser' in type ... does not have an implementation."  Stopping and restarting the site does not resolve the issue but if I simply re-upload the main .dll file (the exact same version of the .dll) to the site then everything works fine again.  For a while, at any rate.

Why would it be okay when newly published but fail after sitting for some time?  Any suggestions on troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had some issues also when I did publish my Web Apps at IIS. When the application goes Idle for some time It fails. Do you have IoC and DI in this application? Are you using OWIN? I solved this issue migrating the IoC initialization to the OWIN Startup class rather than the Global.asax App_Start.

Comment: This project does use DI but is not using OWIN.  I suspect that DI might be heading down the right track.  The getter for CurrentUser is the first attempt that is made to access an object loaded via injection.  If injection is not starting up and working correctly after the app pool is disposed and reloaded then that is the method call that would fail.

Comment: Looks like you have the same issue that I had. The Container is Aufofac?

Comment: Yes, Autofac. Do you have a link to a discussion of your issue?

Comment: As I said, I figure it out that moving the Container to the Startup class make things work properly. I had to do trying and error until Its done, because I couldn't find anything at Stackoverflow, neigther the oficial Autofac forum. I Also registered as InstancePerRequest, post your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

IIS has introduced Suspend action for idle timeout, when site is idle for specified duration, IIS will suspend process, god knows what happens exactly but looks like it just hibernates the process. And waking up may not work, so you can change this action to terminate for idle timeout.

Second option is to keep site awake by using pingdom or site24x7 services.

Answer (score 0):

Could it help to try Azure Web App and set Always On? 
http://azure.microsoft.com/updates/azure-web-sites-adds-always-on/

Comment: That seems like a good thing for the production site when it goes live but for now that option is not available for my dev site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found a solution.

The app start event in global.asax included "var assemblies = System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies();" in order to make sure that everything loads, but that line was -after- the call that was triggering all of the dependency registration.  I cut/pasted that line so that it happens first and the site came up fine when I tried it this morning.